# Spatial temporal query in python with many records

Tags: python, pandas, spatial, temporal

I have a dataframe of 600 000 x/y points with date-time information, along another field 'status', with extra descriptive information

My objective is, for each record:

- sum column 'status' by records that are within a certain spatial temporal buffer

the specific buffer is within t - 8 hours and < 100 meters

Currently I have the data in a pandas data frame.

I could, loop through the rows, and for each record, subset the dates of interest, then calculate a distances and restrict the selection further. However that would still be quite slow with so many records.

- THIS TAKES 4.4 hours to run.

I can see that I could create a 3 dimensional kdtree with x, y, date as epoch time. However, I am not certain how to restrict the distances properly when incorporating dates and geographic distances.

### Here is some reproducible code for you guys to test on:

## Import

```
import numpy.random as npr
import numpy
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, date_range
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
```

## Create data

np.random.seed(111)

## Function to generate test data

```
def CreateDataSet(Number=1):

    Output = []

    for i in range(Number):

        # Create a date range with hour frequency
        date = date_range(start='10/1/2012', end='10/31/2012', freq='H')

        # Create long lat data
        laty = npr.normal(4815862, 5000,size=len(date))
        longx = npr.normal(687993, 5000,size=len(date))

        # status of interest
        status = [0,1]

        # Make a random list of statuses
        random_status = [status[npr.randint(low=0,high=len(status))] for i in range(len(date))]

        # user pool
        user = ['sally','derik','james','bob','ryan','chris']

        # Make a random list of users 
        random_user = [user[npr.randint(low=0,high=len(user))] for i in range(len(date))]

        Output.extend(zip(random_user, random_status, date, longx, laty))

    return pd.DataFrame(Output, columns = ['user', 'status', 'date', 'long', 'lat'])

#Create data  
data = CreateDataSet(3)
len(data)
#some time deltas
before = timedelta(hours = 8)
after = timedelta(minutes = 1)
```

## Function to speed up

```
def work(df):

    output = []
    #loop through data index's
    for i in range(0, len(df)):
    l = []
        #first we will filter out the data by date to have a smaller list to compute distances for

        #create a mask to query all dates between range for date i
        date_mask = (df['date'] >= df['date'].iloc[i]-before) & (df['date'] <= df['date'].iloc[i]+after)
        #create a mask to query all users who are not user i (themselves)
        user_mask = df['user']!=df['user'].iloc[i]
        #apply masks
        dists_to_check = df[date_mask & user_mask]

        #for point i, create coordinate to calculate distances from
        a = np.array((df['long'].iloc[i], df['lat'].iloc[i]))
        #create array of distances to check on the masked data
        b = np.array((dists_to_check['long'].values, dists_to_check['lat'].values))

        #for j in the date queried data
        for j in range(1, len(dists_to_check)):
            #compute the ueclidean distance between point a and each point of b (the date masked data)
            x = np.linalg.norm(a-np.array((b[0][j], b[1][j])))

            #if the distance is within our range of interest append the index to a list
            if x <=100:
                l.append(j)
            else:
                pass
        try:
            #use the list of desired index's 'l' to query a final subset of the data
            data = dists_to_check.iloc[l]
            #summarize the column of interest then append to output list
            output.append(data['status'].sum())
        except IndexError, e:
            output.append(0)
            #print "There were no data to add"

    return pd.DataFrame(output)
```

## Run code and time it

```
start = datetime.now()
out = work(data)
print datetime.now() - start
```

Is there a way to do this query in a vectorized way? Or should I be chasing another technique.

<3

Comment: is nn column a list on each row of all the other x/y coordinates within 100 metres, or are the values of nn the same for all coordinates within 100 metres?

Comment: 'nn' is a list of all the index's of the records that are within 100m.
I am able to pass the list of index's to .iloc[].

Therefore I can iterate through the data and query a df with those points, then create a date query for each record. I will update with an answer if I proceed. I feel like this is a relevant question.

Comment: Can you show an reproducible example of the code you are now using? That will be easier to suggest possible spead-ups.

Comment: I think you can use kd_tree to find all pairs of points whose distance is at most 100m, then theck the timestamp to filter the result further.

Comment: That still has me looping through the whole file. Generally, filtering by date first reduces the number of points i need to calculate distances for to <2000, which is pretty fast. for 2000 points:
10000000 loops, best of 3: 30.4 ns per loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what at least somewhat solves my problem. Since the loop can operate on different parts of the data independently, parallelization makes sense here.

## using Ipython...

```
from IPython.parallel import Client
cli = Client()
cli.ids

cli = Client()
dview=cli[:]

with dview.sync_imports():
    import numpy as np
    import os
    from datetime import timedelta
    import pandas as pd

#We also need to add the time deltas and output list into the function as 
#local variables as well as add the Ipython.parallel decorator

@dview.parallel(block=True)
def work(df):
    before = timedelta(hours = 8)
    after = timedelta(minutes = 1)
    output = []
```

## final time 1:17:54.910206, about 1/4 original time

I would still be very interested for anyone to suggest small speed improvements within the body of the function.